# Retrying failed graphql query with react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have the following example component and I'm hoping when there is a random failure, I can click a button to retry the query manually (through some user interaction). Is this possible by chance? I would also like if the resultant query is successful, then the page gets populated with the data (ie a rerender of sorts).

```
export default () => {
  let { loading, error, data } = useQuery(myGqlQuery)

  if (loading) {
    return <LoadingComponent />
  }

  const reassign = () => {
    // I want this function to somehow retry the query to see if error has subsided
  }

  if (error) {
    return <button onClick={reassign}>Retry Query</button>
  }
```

...

Answer (score 3):

use `refetch()` as `const {..., refetch} = useQuery(QUERY)`

see docs: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `refetch`:

```
export default () => {
  const { loading, error, data, refetch } = useQuery(myGqlQuery)

  if (loading) {
    return <LoadingComponent />
  }

  const reassign = () => {
    refetch()
  }

  if (error) {
    return <button onClick={reassign}>Retry Query</button>
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      // render your data here
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useLazyQuery` instead of `useQuery`.

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-queries-manually

In this way you have to call manually also at the first render inside a useEffect hook but it is easy.

```js
export default () => {
  let [fnToCallQuery, { loading, error, data }] = useLazyQuery(myGqlQuery)

  React.useEffect(() => fnToCallQuery(), []);

  if (loading) {
    return <LoadingComponent />
  }

  if (error) {
    return <button onClick={_ => fnToCallQuery()}>Retry Query</button>
  }

  // return your jsx with fetched data
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: This will throw the error message `React Hook "React.useEffect" is called conditionally` since you are running the fnToCallQuery() function in the React.useEffect() block

Comment: @lomse Sure about that? Initiating queries and mutations from useEffect() is quite common. Maybe you're confusing it with calling another _hook_ within useEffect()? fnToCallQuery is just a normal function.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Not sure what I drunk that day before making that comment.